# Gallery with mixed content types

Tags: magnific-popup

Gallery with mixed content types, it always opens the first element, should open the clicked element

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KvcCJ

Simple example with just images, works fine.

http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/qruJz

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Question was resolved on GitHub https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/146